# iptables Linux Java API or Groovy

Tags: java, linux, api, groovy, iptables

#### I was wondering if there is Linux or Java API that would allow me to perform the command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 67.215.4.101 -j DROP
```

Alternatively if there is away to do this in Groovy, I would like to know about that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy, strings have an `execute()` method:

```
"iptables -A INPUT -s 67.215.4.101 -j DROP".execute()
```

Look at this [page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management).

Of course, there are execution privileges that need to be considered.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't feel comfortable running your java process as root, here is another way to get around that. You could write a simple daemon process written in your favorite language that listens on a FIFO socket( running as root) and then calls iptables. From the example you gave above, you could probably just pass the IP address to the daemon. From the Java program, you can send a FIFO command to the daemon process.

I used this technique recently and it worked well. In my case I used a simple JNI interface to send FIFO messages to the daemon process.

Comment: @Daniel - heh. I meant FIFO, man 3 mkfifo for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  Your best bet is to run that as an external command; e.g. using `System.exec(...)`.

Obviously, that the command would need to be run with root privilege, and that has implications concerning the way that you run it.